# passing props from parent to children in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass props from parent to several children components , but eventually I get the error of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')`
App.js :

```
  render() {
    const {currentUser} = this.props
    return (
      <div id="App" className='loader'>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='women' element={<Women currentUser={currentUser} />} />
```

Women.js:

```
  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) {
        return null;
    }
    const {currentUser} = this.props

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container mx-auto'>
                <HomeHeaderW style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff2e0" }} currentUser={currentUser} />
```

HomeHeaderW.js :

```
function HomeHeaderW() {
   const {currentUser} = this.props
   const [isLogged, setLogged] = useState(false);
   useEffect(() => {
     if(currentUser) {
         setLogged(true)
     }
   });
```

I don't know why I get the undefined error , do you have an idea about this ? Or Am I doing it in the wrong way

Comment: `HomeHeaderW` is not a class based component so I think you cannot use `this.props` but instead your function should have `props` as an input parameter : `function HomeHeaderW(props) { ... }`.  If you have other components with `render` functions then it looks like your project might be mixing class based components with functional components which is why the two things don't quite look/act the same.

Comment: @mr rogers explained what to do to make it work, but the nature of the error message is not react related, but JavaScript related, "this" inside that function is undefined, since that function is declared in the global object, and under "strict mode" you can't have a direct access to global object with "this" keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HomeHeaderW` is a function-based component (`Women` and `App` are class-based components), you cannot get props from `this.props`

You should pass your props on the params

```js
function HomeHeaderW(props) {
  const {
    currentUser
  } = props;

  const [isLogged, setLogged] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      setLogged(true)
    }
  });
```

You can check [this document](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) for a better understanding